# ReactJS - onClick isn't picking up id from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am very new to ReactJS and need some guidance on how to get the below onClick to work (in the CategoryFilter variable).

There are two api calls - one for categories and one for items that belong to one or more of those categories.

When I display the categories they are links, and when clicking on a category link it should pick up that categories id and then pass this to a filter to only show items that belong to the category.

At the moment the below does not pick up the id and so no products show. I have been working on this for two days and am going round in circles, so any help would be much appreciated!

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './CatNav.css';
import axios from 'axios';



class TestPageFour extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    super();

    this.state = {
      categories: [],
      items: [],
      selectedCategoryId: null
    };

    this.onSelectCategory = this.onSelectCategory.bind(this);
  }

  onSelectCategory(id) {
    this.setState({
      selectedCategoryId: id
    });
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(`https://api.gousto.co.uk/products/v2.0/categories`)
      .then(res => {
        const allData = res.data;
        const categories = allData.data;
        this.setState({ categories: categories });
      });
    axios.get(`https://api.gousto.co.uk/products/v2.0/products?includes[]=categories&includes[]=attri`)
      .then(res => {
        const allDataItems = res.data;
        const items = allDataItems.data;
        this.setState({ items: items });
      })
  }


  render() {
    const { categories, items, selectedCategoryId } = this.state;
    const deafultCategory = _.first(categories);
    const selectedCategory = _.find(categories, i => i.id === selectedCategoryId) || deafultCategory;
    return (
      <div>
        <CategoryFilter categories={categories} onSelectCategory={this.onSelectCategory} />
        <ItemList items={items} selectedCategoryId={selectedCategoryId} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


let CategoryFilter = ({ categories, onSelectCategory}) => {
  const links = categories.map(i => (
    <div key={i.id}>
      <a href={i.id} onClick={() => onSelectCategory(i.id)}>
        { i.title }
      </a>
    </div>
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      { links }
    </div>
  )
};

let ItemList = ({items, selectedCategoryId}) => {
  const currentItems = items
    .filter(i => {
      i.categories.map(category => {
        return category.id === selectedCategoryId;
      })})
    .map(i => (
      <div key={i.id}>
        { i.title }
      </div>
    ));
  return (
    <div>
      { currentItems }
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestPageFour
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is a return from within your `filter` method in the `ItemList` function.

```
.filter(i => {
  // Here
  return i.categories.map(category => {
    return category.id === selectedCategoryId;
  })})
.map(i => (
 ...
));
```

But the logic here is incorrect. Because the `map` method inside the `filter` method will always return an array. Instead use the `fiter` method Which is not what you want as a result.
You can try something like this:

```
...
.filter(i => i.categories.filter(category => category.id === selectedCategoryId))
...
```

But that isn't enough. Because when you check for the `category.id` inside each `item`, the filter method will return an **empty array** if the `ids` don't match.

> *Which means you'll always be returning all the `items`*

To fix that, you should return a `boolean` to the upper `filter` operation.

```
...
// Instead of this:
const currentItems = items.filter(i=> i.categories.filter(category => category.id === selectedCategoryId))

// Something like this:
const currentItems = items.filter(i=> {
   const categoryExists = i.categories.filter(category => category.id === selectedCategoryId))
   return categoryExists.length > 0;
}) // then map through and render them!!
...
```

Here's a working exampl:

[image: Edit Fix 'show items when select categories']

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: and it should be `i.categories.find`, not `i.categories.map`

Comment: Thank you for such a speedy response! I have made this edit, but it still isn't working - the trouble seems to be when I console.log(selectedCategory) after the render - it is returning the defaultCategory (the first item in the list) and if I then console.log(selectCategoryId) it returns null - so what I defined in constructor - so it doesn't seem to be picking up on the category id when I click to re state the id to pull through into the render!

Comment: I know what the problem is. See the changes I made in my answer!